# Online service or software for fundraising site?

Tags: web-services, software

I've got a client who is looking to have a fundraising site built in a matter of days so there's very little time for custom building something.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any software or online service that might be customised.

The fundraising site would operate in the following way (for example):

- Users register
- Registered users select a "challenge" to complete, ie. 5km run every day for 4 weeks
- Friends/family of the registered user sponsor the user $5 for every day they run $5km
- Friends/family of the registered user can also make a donation (ie. not requiring sponsorship)
- Donations & sponsorships would be made direct to the fundraising site (ie. not via registered user)
- Registered users can link their challenge progress to their facebook page

If anyone has some ideas, I'd really appreciate. Just to be clear, I'm looking for an online service or software that can be customised.

Comment: Just an observation, but things involving user registration(read: privacy concerns) and money(read: credit card information) are probably not things you want to build in "a matter of days." Your client needs an expectation adjustment. The challenge details are unusual enough I'd guess that at the very least that will need some custom work, especially since the implication seems there will be multiple challenges, with different requirements. I'm tempted to flag this as too localized, but let's see if anyone can come up with something.

Comment: Thanks Su, I agree it's not realistic and I'm really not sure I could do it in the timeframe. Re credit card information, I think Paypal would be the way to go as it would not require merchant gateways and so on. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've decided to decline the job described above, I did find [Convio's Common Ground Fundraising](http://www.commongroundcrm.com/) which may be of assistance to others in future. The downside is their pricing.

See [Convio's API & Webservices](http://open.convio.com/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

- PayPal would be the way to go for the checkout or Google Checkout.
- Jotform is also a great tool and very easy to use. You can add donation check out and link it with PayPal and customize the forms in a matter of minutes.